# as3 hitTestObject with for loop

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, hittest

I am building a pacman style game, and I am looking to shorten my code.
The stage contains 92 instances with instance names of food1, food2, etc.
When the player(pacman) hits one of the instances Im wanting to call a funcion.

I started writing it out like this... it works but I don't want to duplicate this 92 times!

```
if( player.hitTestObject(food1) ) {
    updateScore();
}

if( player.hitTestObject(food2) ) {
    updateScore();
}
```

Now I'm trying something along these lines, but with no success yet.

```
function collectFood() {
    var i:Number;
    var pGroup:String

    for (i=0; i<92; i++) {
        pGroup= "food" + i;
        if( player.hitTestObject( MovieClip(pGroup) ) ) {
            pCount+= 1;
            MovieClip(pGroup).y=-300;
            updateScore();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Here's your chance to get into writing classes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into storing your food in an `Array`.

Set up an Array:

```
var food:Array = [];
```

Add your food items into this array (wherever applicable):

```
food.push(myFood);
```

And then you can use `for each` to run through the items in this Array:

```
for each(var i:MovieClip in food)
{
    // do stuff with i
    // i represents an instance of your food

    if(player.hitTestObject(i))
    {
        pCount ++;
        pGroup.y -= 300;

        updateScore();
    }
}
```

If you have your food on the stage and want to add them all into this Array, just do this:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i<92; i++)
{
    food.push(MovieClip(this["food"] + i));
}
```

---

I strongly suggest that you look into [Object-oriented programming (OOP) for ActionScript-3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/oop_as3.html). Using OOP you'll be able to create a `class` for your `Food` and [encapsulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)) everything that a piece of Food should do.

It will also allow you to have much cleaner and readable code, particularly in the above `for each` loop, which could look like this:

```
for each(var i:Food in food)
{
    // i is an instance of Food
}
```

As an aesthetic benefit, using an application like [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) will provide extremely helpful tooltips based on what you add to your Food class, eg:

[image]

Comment: when you use food.push(myFood); what is (myFood) referencing?

Comment: An instance of `Food` (or in your case a `MovieClip` that represents food).